# How do I access methods within the objects I put in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on re-creating the game "The Oregon Trail" and have created an object array, but can't figure out how to use the methods within the superclass. I have a superclass, `Location`, and subclasses, `City` `Fort` `River` and `Landmark`. Here is my code for instantiating the array:

```
    City     independence      = new City("Independence", 102);
    River    kansas            = new River("Kansas", 82);
    River    bigBlue           = new River("Big Blue River", 118);
    Fort     kearney           = new Fort("Fort Kearney", 86);
    Landmark chimneyRock       = new Landmark("Chimney Rock", 86);
    Fort     laramie           = new Fort("Fort Laramie", 190);
    Landmark independenceRock  = new Landmark("Independence Rock", 102);
    Landmark southPass         = new Landmark("South Pass", 57, 125);
    River    green             = new River("Green River", 143);
    Fort     bridger           = new Fort("Fort Bridger", 162);
    Landmark sodaSprings       = new Landmark("Soda Springs", 57);
    Fort     hall              = new Fort("Fort Hall", 182);
    River    snake             = new River("Snake River", 113);
    Fort     boise             = new Fort("Fort Boise", 160);
    Landmark blueMountains     = new Landmark("Blue Mountains", 55, 125);
    Fort     wallaWalla        = new Fort("Fort Walla Walla", 120);
    Landmark dalles            = new Landmark("The Dalles", 100);

    kansas.setWidth(620);
    kansas.setDepth(4);
    bigBlue.setWidth(300);
    bigBlue.setDepth(6);
    green.setWidth(400);
    green.setDepth(20);
    snake.setWidth(1000);
    snake.setDepth(7);

    Object[] locations = new Object[] {
        independence,
        kansas,
        bigBlue,
        kearney,
        chimneyRock,
        laramie,
        independenceRock,
        southPass,
        green,
        bridger,
        sodaSprings,
        hall,
        snake,
        boise,
        blueMountains,
        wallaWalla,
        dalles
    };
```

The parameters for the class instantiations are either (string name, int distance to next landmark) or (string name, int distance to option A, distance to option B) as there are forks in the road. That should be irrelevant for my question though.

Comment: Declare it with `Location[] locations = new Location[] {` (or better yet, use a `List<Location>` instead of an array).

Comment: how would I use the list? and how would I call them back in the future? I originally had it as `Location[] locations = new Location[]{` and couldnt get it working.

Comment: Showing how to use a `List` is probably a better job for a tutorial. Can you please show how you tried to use it when it wasn't working?

Comment: sure! I have a function within the `Location` class called `getName` which is passed through the instantiation of each class. I tried doing the following:

`String n = locations[0].getName();`

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to contain a [mcve]? Here's [a quick demo where the code is working](https://ideone.com/mXoXtZ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What method do you want to call?

Usually, if you are going to put a bunch of objects in the same array or the same collection, it's because there's one or more common methods that you plan to perform on *all* of them (or, *could* perform on *any* of them.)

In that case, you'll usually want to declare an `interface` that captures whatever it is that the objects all have in common.

In your example, you have `Landmark`, `Fort`, and `River` objects.  What do they have in common?  Well, for one thing, they all have names.  So you might have

```
interface Location {
    String getName();
    ...other methods that apply to all different kinds of location...
}
```

And then you might have

```
class Landmark implements Location {
    String getName() { return ...; }
    ...other methods that apply to all different kinds of location...
    ...other methods that only apply to Landmarks...
}

class Fort implements Location {
    String getName() { return ...; }
    ...other methods that apply to all different kinds of location...
    ...other methods that only apply to Forts...
}

etc.
```

Then, if you declare your array like this...

```
Location locations[] = new Location[] { independence, kansas, bigBlue, ...};
```

The compiler will allow you to apply any of the `Location` methods to members of the array.

```
for (int i=0 ; i<locations.length ; i++) {
    System.out.println(locations[i].getName());
}
```